# How can I get all custom fields that are Hidden from all profiles?

Tags: field-level-security, fls, hidden-fields

I got responsibility for another SF instance.
The objects all have 100's of fields, of which many are hidden from all users (historically, they would not delete the field, but hide it from all users - great practice IMO)

Now, comes the time, we can delete these fields. but going through them is very time consuming.

Any idea how I can get a report/list/rest of all the fields that are hidden from all profiles ?  FLS settings offcourse.

Answer (score 1):

Below query will help you to get the required details. *You need to add your apex code on the top of that. Example - to find hidden fields you may have list of all available fields and subtracted by below query field list*

**Query-**

```sql
SELECT   Parent.Profile.Name, Field, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsRead, SobjectType
 FROM    FieldPermissions
```

***Please be aware, it'll have more records than 50K so add proper conditions.***

Documentation Link -
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm